# Frequent, unexplainable "Download unsuccessful" using stock browser on Droid 3

Tags: downloading, stock-browser, sip

I have been experiencing this frustrating issue with my phone where it might take several attempts to download a file through the stock browser. An example would be how it took 5 attempts to download the dropbox beta apk file.

This is frustrating because it wastes my time and my bandwidth. Downloading on firefox for android is okay, but probably because it caches the files, so if you save an image, it just copies it from the cache to your downloads directory.

There have been a few instances where I have witnessed it hitting 100% complete and displaying "Download complete" but then changing to "Download unsuccessful" 3-5 seconds later.

Until today, I didn't have an external SD card, so I figured that perhaps the file was getting corrupted because something else was reading or writing from the card at the same time. But I can't find a way to get the stock browser to change the path it writes downloaded files to.

Is there a way to fix this? Perhaps a way to see why the filesystem is marking the file as unclean? I checked my logcat app, but didn't see anything useful.

I'm considering using TitaniumBackup and freezing the stock browser and replacing it with Dolphin or something. I prefer having two browsers as some places I have two logins and hate constantly logging in and logging out, additionally when I need to look something up "real quick" I use the stock browser as it is light-weight for quick tasks.

For record sake, I am using stock android on a rooted Droid 3, but this problem has been happening before I was rooted.

Additionally, this is an insurance replacement that I got January 18 of 2012, but didn't touch it between January 31-Oct 11, 2012. So I do not know if the data radio is burnt out and is corrupting the packets.

**Update:** I used a SQL Editor to look at the downloads database. It seems that the files that didn't download saved with a status code of *489*. At first I thought this was an HTTP status code, but turns out to be a SIP protocol status code. Research finds that it is returned when the client sends a malformed Event header.  Any clue what is causing this?

**Another Update:** Just adding more information has it becomes available. This seems to be happening beyond the stock browser. Last night I decided to finally update all of my apps that have been pending updates for a week. Several of them took several attempts to download as they'd error out like seen in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot Showing Download issues]

Please note that the above screenshot happened while I was on wifi. Generally I am on mobile data, so the problem isn't because of a poor wifi signal.